# Java servlet filter lost format info, how to fix it?

Tags: java, html, servlets, format, filtering

I have a servlet filter looks like this :

```
public class ServletFilter implements Filter
{
  String Token="";

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { }

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest,ServletResponse servletResponse,FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException,ServletException
  {
    HttpServletRequest request=(HttpServletRequest)servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response=(HttpServletResponse)servletResponse;

    response.getWriter().write("Request intercepted ...\n<P>\n");   
    Token=request.getParameter("token");
    if (Token==null || Token.trim().length()<1)
    {
      filterChain.doFilter(request,response);
//      filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse);
      return;
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

After filtering, it couldn't properly display Html format, as you can see from the following screenshots, the top part is before the filtering and it's the way it should be, the lower part is what it looks like after filtering, why ? How to fix it ?

[image]

Comment: How about instead of screenshots view source in browser and look at the HTML

Comment: Check if commenting out `response.getWriter().write("Request intercepted ...\n<P>\n");` fixes the issue. It could be that this string messes up the format, or if the target request handler tries to do 'response.getOutputStream()', then the request may fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern of use is incorrect, or at least unsafe, for Servlet filters.

Let's say for example that your interception filter runs first in the list of filters. One of the first thing it does is calling `getWriter` on the response.

1. Once a call to `getWriter` is issued, the servlet container is free to start flushing the HTTP header of the response right away. So any headers you have not yet set (such as Content Type) will be ignored. Which is pretty bad if you actually output HTML content.
2. Once a call to `getWriter`is issued, the rest of the chain you (may) invoke can not call `getOutputStream`without having an `IllegalStateException` (as per javadoc). You better be sure of what you do, including how whatever framework you may use down the road does, so as to be sure no-one ever calls `getOutputStream` further away along the chain !
3. You start writing (what looks like) HTML content in your Filter. But chances are nobody ever wrote the opening of the document ! ( ... ). So you're probably creating invalid HTML content anyway.

Bottom line is : you should not use servlet filters to write "body level" HTML (or indeed many types of content) content if you are going to forward the request to the rest of the execution chain in order to render a full page. Most probably (that is : unless you precisely know what you are forwarding to, and where you are coming from - which is kind of counter-nature for Filters, you generally want them not to be dependant on other filters), you'll end up creating malformed content, or worse, putting your ServletResponse into a IllegalState.

Still, you can do some things. Such as adding headers to your HTTP Response, adding a cookie, logging to your server side console, setting a request/session parameter that you can use later (in your JSPs ?) to display the content this "Request Intercepted" string at some later stage.